# CS50 week 1 pset (mario)- the user prompt doesn't seem to be working as the #s dont print although n is less than 8

Tags: c, cs50, edx

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n=get_int("Size: ");
    }
    while (n < 8);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
       printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I want the code to display the number of `#`s that the user prompts it to, Given that the number prompted is between 1 and 8. Here, the code reprompts the used when the prompt given is less than 8 and displays when its more. Which is the opposite of what I wish to achieve.

Moreover, the code seems to work the way I want it to when I change `(n < 8)` to `(n > 8)`. Kindly tell me why this occurs.

Comment: What do you want that loop to do? It shall ask again and again until you get a valid number. That means you must keep asking as long as you have invalid numbers. And `n>8` is invalid if you want to allow only values `1..8`

Comment: You want: `while ((n < 1) || (n > 8))`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Moreover, the code seems to work the way I want it to when I change (n < 8) to (n > 8). Kindly tell me why this occurs." Well, try to think about the code logically. In the original code, what does `n < 8` mean? When that is true, what will happen - will the loop run again, or will it exit? Therefore, will the user be asked for another number, or will the program continue on with the number that was chosen? Now - when `n` is less than 8, what **should** happen? More precisely: what are the rules that tell you that the user should be asked again?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the effect of the *conditional* that you use.

Have some fun. Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h> // this is 'subordinate' to <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    do // top of loop
    {
        int n;
        n = get_int("Size (0 to 8): "); // inform user of valid range

        for (int i = 0; n <= 8 && i < n; i++) // inner loop
        {
           printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");

    } while (n <= 8); // exit loop when 'n' > 8

    printf("Bye-bye\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The do-while loop will always guarantee an execution once and based on the condition inside the while statement it will repeat.

Given this, what is your condition?

"n < 8"

You are effectively telling your program to repeat the lines inside of the block {} as long as the user input continues to be less than 8.

Review conditional operators and try it out yourself.

Try using if statements such as

```
if(x < 8)
{
  printf("x is less than 8\n");
}

if(x > 8)
{
  printf("x is greater than 8\n");
}
```

And look at what executes and why. Ask yourself what are you trying to achieve and then review your code. Remember the computer only does what we tell it to do. Best of luck!

Hint: if its doing the opposite, than maybe you should do the opposite.